# How to delete duplicate elements from VBscript/VBA array to use in drop down box in Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, vbscript

I'm finding a lot of articles close to mine, but not quite what I'm looking for. I'm working with the IBM Personal Communications emulator to gather patient history data. There can be several pages of claims on the patient history, so the service codes used later in the program need to be gathered and saved in an array. Once duplicates are removed, the remaining codes will be stored in a drop down box.

```
' Copies entire current history screen
MHIScreen = objUNET.autECLPS.GetText(3, 1, 1680)

' Location of the place of service code header
POSLoc = InStr(MHIScreen, "PS  SVC")

' Location of service code
ServLoc = POSLoc + 3

' Used for array index
j = 1
Row = 4

Do
    Serv(j) = Mid(MHIScreen, ServLoc, 6)
    Range("D" & Row).Value = Serv(j)
    ServLoc = ServLoc + 320
    j = j + 1
    Row = Row + 1
Loop Until SMonth > EMonth
```

The output of this could look like this:

```
12345
12345
23456
12345
34567
34567
12345
98765
```

The desired result would be to filter through the duplicates and end up with this:

```
12345
23456
34567
98765
```

These would the be put into a drop down box for the user to choose from. I wanted to see where in the element one particular code would be located, but when I add the following line of code, I get 0 because j is already higher than the index of the last code and `Serv(j)` is empty:

```
Result = InStr(Serv(j), "34567")
```

Is there anyone who can guide me to a solution?

Comment: (Unrelated to your question) Does `Range("D" & Row).Value` work in VBScript?  I would have thought you would need to specify the Excel `Application` object that you are using in order to get to the `Range` property.

Comment: How do you set the bounds of the `Serv` array?

Comment: Note that your question has nothing to do with duplicates in the array; rather it is how to find the first index of a given element within an array.

Comment: `YowE3K` - Yes, that works. Excel `Application` object was specified, but due to the length of the program, it needs to be assumed that all necessary objects were created. `Zev Spitz` - No, `Serv(j)` is an array of data from IBM PCOMM and `Row` refers to a row in Excel. The array data is being entered into the spreadsheet. My question still has to do with finding duplicates in an array and then removing them...or not allowing them into the array after the first one is found. As for setting the bounds, there aren't any. The array stops receiving data when search criteria is met.

Comment: Notifying other commenters about your comment (the author of a question or an answer is always notified) is done using the `@` syntax, like so: @Lou. You can only explicitly notify one person within your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who reached out to help me. With their combined efforts, and a little extra research on what they were trying to tell me, I have came up with a solution that works.

```
Dim objDictionary, strItem, intItems, p, strKey, CodeList
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each strItem In Serv
    If Not objDictionary.Exists(strItem) Then
        objDictionary.Add strItem, strItem
    End If
Next

intItems = objDictionary.Count - 1
ReDim arrItems(intItems)
p = 0

For Each strKey In objDictionary.Keys
    arrItems(p) = strKey
    p = p + 1
Next

For Each strItem In arrItems
    With Sheet1.RHICodes
        .AddItem strItem
    End With
Next
```

This now takes all of the service codes that I collected from IBM PCOMM, enters them into an array, uses the `Scripting.Dictionary` to sort them, then create another array with only the options I want with no duplicates and enters them into a drop down box.

Comment: Why do you need to check if `objDictionary.Exists(strItem)`? Don't use `Add`; rather use the default property: `objDictionary(strItem) = strItem`.

Comment: Also, you don't need a second array for this; you can iterate over the dictionary's keys directly: `For Each strItem In objDictionary.Items: Sheet1.RHICodes.AddItem strItem: Next`

Comment: @Zev Spitz I copied the code from the URL below.  It had some of the elements of your `Scripting.Dictionary` example, but I needed to change a few variables to suit my needs.  I ran it once and it did exactly what I needed.  I can play around with your suggestions once I'm finished with the rest of the project as I have a lot more to develop.  Thanks for all your advice.  It is greatly appreciated. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2006/10/27/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-items-from-an-array/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your code has to do the following:

1. Generate a collection with an arbitrary number of elements, from a string
2. Store the elements in the cells of an Excel worksheet
3. Get another collection with only the unique elements

---

#### 1. Generate a collection with an arbitrary number of elements

The most basic technique is to use `Redim Preserve` to continuously resize the array:

```
Dim arr(), j
j = 0
Do
    Redim Preserve arr(j)
    arr(j) = Mid(MHIScreen, ServLoc, 6)
    ServLoc = ServLoc + 320
    j = j + 1
Loop Until SMonth > EMonth
```

However, if you are using VBA, then a `Collection` object is the natural choice here, because you don't have to worry about extending the size of the array:

```
Dim col As New Collection
Do
    col.Add Mid(MHIScreen, ServLoc, 6)
    ServLoc = ServLoc + 320
Loop Until SMonth > EMonth
```

If you are using VBScript, then I would suggest using a .NET [`ArrayList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) in the same way ([besides its many other benefits](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_data_arraylist.php)):

```
Dim al
Set al = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Do
    al.Add Mid(MHIScreen, ServLoc, 6)
    ServLoc = ServLoc + 320
Loop Until SMonth > EMonth
```

NB. In your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45066915/how-to-delete-duplicate-elements-from-vbscript-vba-array-to-use-in-drop-down-box/45067150#comment77136346_45067150), you mentioned sorting the array. One of the benefits of `ArrayList` over `Collection` is that it has built-in sorting, via the [`Sort` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k6e334t(v=vs.110).aspx). If sorting the values is also a goal, I would use an `ArrayList` even in VBA.

---

#### 2. Store the elements in the cells of an Excel worksheet

If you're using an array, you can simply set the `Value` property of an appropriately sized range. For an array:

```
'app is a variable referring to the Excel Application instance
Dim rng
Set rng = app.Workbooks("MyWorkbook").Worksheets("MyWorksheet").Range("D4").Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1)
rng.Value = xlApp.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
```

For a collection or an ArrayList, you have to iterate and write the values by hand. A collection's first index is `1`:

```
Dim rng As Range, i As Integer
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
For i = 1 To col.Count
    rng.Value = col.Item(i)
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
Next
```

while an ArrayList's first index is `0`:

```
Dim rng, i
Set rng = Application.Workbooks("MyWorkbook").Worksheets("MyWorksheet").Range("D4")
For i = 0 To al.Count -1
    rng.Value = al.Item(i)
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
Next
```

---

#### 3. Get another collection with only the unique elements

You can use a [Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx) for this purpose:

```
Dim dict, x
Set dict  = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each x In arr 'can be used equally well with a Collection or an ArrayList
    dict(x) = 1 '1 is a dummy value
Next

'prints the keys of the dictionary, which are unique
For Each x In dict.Keys
    Debug.Print x
Next
```

---

The code in your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45089286/111794) can be simplified as follows:

1. As long as you use the default `Item` property, there is no need to check if the key already exists in the dictionary. Only if you use the `Add` method will you have a problem when adding an existing key.
2. You can iterate over the keys in the dictionary directly; you don't need a second array:

Like so:

```
Dim objDictionary, strItem
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each strItem In Serv
    objDictionary(strItem) = 1
Next
For Each strItem In objDictionary.Keys
    Sheet1.RHICodes.AddItem strItem
Next
```

Comment: "Presumably, you are defining the bounds of the `Serv` array"...I get it now. You mean `Dim Serv(200) As String`? Yes, I'm setting the bounds higher than the amount of rows I'm collecting from. I've ran into that issue not knowing ahead of time how many rows I will be searching. Please see my reply to Brian. How would I call `IndexOf` to send the `enumerable` and `toFind`? That seems to be the issue I'm facing with using a function to sort an array.

Comment: @Lou This answer is now complete. It includes how to write values from the array/collection/ArrayList into Excel. I would strongly suggest that you clarify whether you are working with VBA (which has typed variables and `Collection`) or VBScript (which has neither).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array of string containing your output, the following code will produce your desired result:

```
Public Function TestRemoveDupsAndSort()

   'all your preceding code has been removed for clarity

   Do
      Serv(j) = Mid(MHIScreen, ServLoc, 6)
      Range("D" & Row).Value = Serv(j)
      ServLoc = ServLoc + 320
      j = j + 1
      Row = Row + 1
   Loop Until SMonth > EMonth

   result = RemoveDupsAndSort(Serv)
End Function



Public Function RemoveDupsAndSort(data() As String) As String()
   On Error Resume Next

   Dim i As Integer
   Dim j As Integer
   Dim c As Collection
   Dim d() As String

   'sort and remove dups
   Set c = New Collection

   For i = LBound(data) To UBound(data)
      For j = 1 To c.Count
         If data(i) < c(j) Then
            c.Add data(i), data(i), j
         End If
      Next

      If j - 1 = c.Count Then c.Add data(i), data(i)
   Next

   'convert from a collection back to an array
   ReDim d(0 To c.Count - 1)

   For i = 0 To c.Count - 1
      d(i) = c(i + 1)
   Next

   RemoveDupsAndSort= d
End Function
```

Comment: Ok...assuming `data()` is referring to `Serv(i)`, is there a specific way to send the data? I added your code, then added `Call RemoveDupsAndSort(Serv(i))` to see if it would work and I get an error message saying `Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected`. When I have `Call RemoveDupsAndSort(Serv(i) As String)`, it highlights "As" and I get `Expected: list separator or )`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just pass 'Serv' to the function.

Comment: I still receive the same type mismatch error. It stops at the opening line for the function that `Serv(i)` is in and gives the mismatch error. Nothing ever gets put into `Serv(i)`.

Comment: @Lou I modified my example to hopefully show you how to call the function.

Comment: There must be something I'm doing wrong. Now it's highlighting `Serv` in your modified code and still giving the type mismatch. I have `Dim Serv(200) As String`. Should that be `Dim Serv(200) As Array`? Never mind...no such thing. Not sure how my array could be a type mismatch.

Comment: @Lou 'Dim Serv(200) As String' should be perfect.  I am not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: I decided to take all the code out of your function and place it where I was calling the function instead of actually calling it, then changed all `data()` to `Serv()`. Now, this is giving me the type mismatch error: `c.Add Serv(g), Serv(g)`. Any ideas? I've worked with regular variables, but arrays are fairly new to me. I know how they work, but passing their contents to some other entity is beyond me at this point. I hope to learn something out of this.

Comment: It seems `g` never increments in the `For...Next` loop. It's showing 0. That, and `Serv(g)` is empty.

Comment: Verify that Serv has the data you expect when your Do Loop finishes.

Comment: Ok...I tried that. I added `MsgBox Serv(10)` at the end of the loop and I was able to pull up one of the service codes, so there is data in the array. I'm just not sure how to get it out of the array for sorting. I haven't found anything on the internet close to what I need to do. You and Zev are helping, but I'm not able to see the results. You got me close to a solution, but I'm still unsure why I can't sort through the array.

Comment: I think I found the error. I stepped through each line in Excel and it `Set c = New Collection`, it set `g` to 0, which is the `LBound` of my array, then, after going to `For h = 1 To c.Count`, it goes straight to `If h - 1 = c.Count Then c.Add Serv(g), Serv(g)`. Seeing as the `For` loop sets `h = 1` in the first round, not sure why it skipped over the code within, but `c.Count` is 0 and `h - 1` is also 0...that's why it goes to `c.Add Serv(g), Serv(g)` and errors out. Now, if I only knew enough about this process to fix it...